# Passing structures in functions when the structure comes from an "array of structures"

Tags: c, struct

In the book "*C Programming: A Modern Approach*" the following quasi-code is supplied to the reader:

```
struct part {
  int number;
  char name[NAME_LEN+1];
  int on_hand;
} part1;

void print_part (struct part p)
{
  ...
}

struct part inventory[100];

print_part(inventory[i]);

inventory[i].number=883;

inventory[i].name[0] = `\0`
```

So, in summary, the author creates a data type called `struct part`, creates a function called `print_part` that takes as its argument a variable `p` of data type `struct part`, creates an array called `inventory` that stores 100 different structures of type `struct part`, and then makes the following call to the aforementioned function: `print_part(inventory[i])`, where `i` could take on any arbitrary values between 0 and 99.

---

In the above function call, is `inventory[i]` functioning as a pointer? At first I thought *certainly not* (because `print_part`'s prototype statement specifies that the function's parameter is a struct variable...not a pointer to struct).

However, the subsequent usage of `inventory[i].number=883` and `inventory[i].name[0]='\0'` made me reconsider that, perhaps, it *does* function as a pointer.

In the case of `inventory[i].name[0]`, it seems like `inventory[i]` is establishing a **base address** and from that base address, there is an **offset** to the 2nd field of the `struct part` data type, `name`. This strikes me as very "pointer-esque". Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The struct is passed by value, meaning that `print_part` receives a *copy* of `inventory[i]`. There is no "*functioning as a pointer*" involved, and I don't see in the question anything that would suggest that, so I am not sure where the confusion lies that prompted the question.

Comment: @dxiv it was mostly because of the base address that seems to be implicitly "offered up" in the statements involving the `.` operator. So I guess the question was not necessarily specific to "arrays" per say...more so to struct variables.

Comment: `array[i]` refers to the `i`'th element in an `array`. There is really no difference whether the array is `int[]` or `struct part[]`. And a function that takes a (non-array type) argument receives it by value, again no difference whether is a plain `int` or a `struct part`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above function call, is inventory[i] functioning as a pointer?

No.  The type of `inventory[i]` is `struct part`.  It is passed to the function *by value*, just like any other function argument.<sup>*</sup>

> At first I thought certainly not (because print_part's prototype statement specifies that the function's parameter is a struct variable...not a pointer to struct).

And you were right to think that.

> However, the subsequent usage of `inventory[i].number=883` and
> `inventory[i].name[0]='\0'` made me reconsider that, perhaps, it does
> function as a pointer.

I'm not seeing the connection there.  The `.` in those expressions is the operator for accessing a structure member.  Its left-hand operand must be a structure, not a pointer to one.  If `inventory[i]` were a pointer then the idiomatic way to access the members of the structure to which it points would be with the `->` operator, of the form `array_of_pointers[i]->member = value`.

> In the case of `inventory[i].name[0]`, it seems like `inventory[i]` is
> establishing a base address and from that base address, there is an
> offset to the 2nd field of the struct part data type, name. This
> strikes me as very "pointer-esque".

Most objects have associated storage, which has a characteristic address of appropriate pointer type.  When you access an object, you can think of it as accessing the memory at that object's address.  Sure, you can call that "pointeresque", but that does not make the expression designating the object a pointer in the C sense.  Pointers introduce an extra level of indirection that is not present in your `inventory[i]`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Perhaps someone is saying "not arrays!" right now.  That's right, arrays are not passed to functions by value, because they are not passed to functions *at all*.  In almost all contexts where a sub-expression of array type appears in an expression, it is automatically replaced by a by a pointer to the first array element.  A function call's argument list is not among the exceptions.  Thus, it is impossible even to express passing an array to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C function **similarly** to pointers.  That is, when you pass them as arguments to functions, the address of the first element is what is passed.  In addition, the array dereference syntax, `array[i]`, is syntactic sugar for `*(array+i)`.  So, in many situations, you can treat arrays like pointers.

However, it must be kept in mind that, despite these similarities, arrays are **not** pointers.  This can be seen, for example, in how `sizeof` treats them.  If you have `unsigned char array[100];`, then `sizeof(array)` is 100.  However, if you then assign `unsigned char *ptr=array;`, then `sizeof(ptr)` is the size of the pointer and not the array.

In your case, `inventory[i]` is not a pointer but a `struct part`.  As mentioned above, it is a convenient expression meaning `*(inventory+i)`.  That is, `inventory+i` is the address of the `i`th element of the array and `inventory[i]` provides you that element by dereferencing that address.